# Jenkins: "${env.SVN_REVISION}" variable returns null

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I would like to read the revision number from Jenkins job when the job fails

Revision number:

[image]

Job script:

```
failure {
        echo 'JENKINS PIPELINE FAILED'

         notifyBitbucket 
            commitSha1: "${env.SVN_REVISION}", 
            considerUnstableAsSuccess: false, 
            credentialsId: 'UFCBitbucket', 
            disableInprogressNotification: true, 
            ignoreUnverifiedSSLPeer: true, 
            includeBuildNumberInKey: false, 
            prependParentProjectKey: false, 
            projectKey: '', 
            stashServerBaseUrl: 'https://bitbucket.url.local:8080'
    }
```

I have trouble with Jenkins environment variable - "${env.SVN_REVISION}". This variable returns null value.

I can not solve this problem. Please help to solve this problem
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the env-variable `SVN_REVISION` does even exist.

All available Git-plugin env-variables can be seen [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin#environment-variables) (and the Jenkins' ones [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables)).

I would suggest you use the following environment-variable to get the revision:

> GIT_COMMIT -  SHA1 of the commit used in this build

On the other hand you can get the revision also by executing the git command directly per sh / bash:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Comment: GIT_COMMIT also returns a null value

Comment: Can you please execute a 'git rev-parse HEAD' in the stage and check if there is printed something. The commit should usually get you the revision as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.This solution helped me. I get revision number with this script
    
revNum = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD')

Comment: Ok, great. I will complete the answer :)

Comment: Feel free to give me some internet points by marking the answer as correct if you are satisfied with it :)